# Gradle jar doLast

Tags: gradle

How to make a copy in the **resources/app** folder. After the other module is compiled

```
jar {
    dependsOn(project(':portal-frontend').tasks.findByName("compileGwt"))
    into("app") {
      File configFile = file(project(':portal-frontend').tasks.findByName("compileGwt").buildDir)
      println configFile.listFiles()
      from project(':portal-frontend').tasks.findByName("compileGwt").buildDir
      //from compileGwt.buildDir
    }
  }
}
```

I have 2 submodule **portal-backend** and **portal-frontend**

- **portal-backend** - spring boot project
- **portal-frontend** - gwt project

So I want. When **portal-frontend** compile. Copy build resource from **portal-frontend** to  **portal-ackend**

Something like this https://gist.github.com/marcokrikke/5481001

But I have multimodule structure

[image]

Comment: A copy of what? Which other module? We can't read in minds. Explain your problem so that we can understand it.

Comment: I added some info